# Сигнал SIGFPE вместо NaN

Tags: c++, linux, c, signal

В некоторых linux системах вместо исключения в операции с плавающей точкой (сигнал SIGFPE) появляется значение NaN и вероятность отыскать ошибку близка к нулю и о существовании ошибки можно лишь догадываться, когда в конце появилось NaN. Хотелось бы, чтобы такое проблемное место убивало программу (тогда отладчик может помочь отыскать проблемное место). Собственно говоря, суть вопроса в том, как сделать, что бы ошибка в операции с плавающей точкой приводила к SIGFPE.

Comment: Если программа ваша, то используйте `feenableexcept()`: http://jayconrod.com/posts/33/trapping-floating-point-exceptions-in-linux

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В реализации libc от GNU есть нестандартная функция `feenableexcept()`¹. Она же есть и во многих других libc (в том числе {Free,Open}BSD и uclibc). В качестве аргумента она принимает битовую маску исключительных ситуаций (аналогично `fesetexceptflag()` и др.):

- `FE_DIVBYZERO` — деление на ноль
- `FE_OVERFLOW`  — переполнение
- `FE_UNDERFLOW` — обратное переполнение
- `FE_INEXACT`   — неточный результат
- `FE_INVALID`   — неверная операция

Все эти макросы определены только если платформа их поддерживает. Также определён макрос `FE_ALL_EXCEPT`, который представляет комбинацию всех вышеописанных.

Также для отмены сигнала есть `fedisableexcept()`.

Как и многие другие расширения GNU, они требует определения *features-test* макроса `_GNU_SOURCE` до включения каких-либо системных хедеров. К сожалению, в Linux man-pages обе эти функции слабо документированы: о ней упомянуто только вскользь в [`man fenv`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fenv). , так что за какими-то подробностями лучше обратиться к исходникам и/или к справке из других ОС.

К сожалению, после получения `SIGFPE` восстановить нормальную работу непосредственно с точки возникновения сигнала невозможно, так что останется только завершиться (или сделать `longjmp()`, см. комментарии). Так что, пожалуй, данные функции ограничены к использованию только отладкой. Возврат из обработчика сигнала приведёт к зацикливанию т.к. выполнение продолжится с той же инструкции, которая вызвала ошибку.

#### Как это работает

Эти функции работают без какой-либо магии со стороны компилятора или системы. Всё завязано исключительно на возможности процессора. На x86 просто устанавливаются соответствующие биты в управляющем регистре `CW` для x87 и, при возможности, в `MXCSR` для SSE (см. [`FLDCW`](http://www.club155.ru/x86cmdfpu/FLDCW) и [`LDMXCSR`](http://www.club155.ru/x86cmdsimd/LDMXCSR) соответственно). Далее при определении соответствующей ситуации процессор просто выкинет исключение, которое обработает ядро и отправит сигнал текущему процессу.

#### Пример

Подсказка: дабы получить разные ошибки, нужно раскомментировать строки в конце:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fenv.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define BUF_SZ 1024

void sigfpe_hdl(int signum, siginfo_t *si, void *ctx) {
  if (signum == SIGFPE) {
    char buf[BUF_SZ];
    char *msg;
    switch (si->si_code) { /* see `man 2 sigaction` for the list */
      case FPE_INTDIV: msg = "Integer divide by zero"          ; break;
      case FPE_INTOVF: msg = "Integer overflow"                ; break;
      case FPE_FLTDIV: msg = "Floating-point divide by zero"   ; break;
      case FPE_FLTOVF: msg = "Floating-point overflow"         ; break;
      case FPE_FLTUND: msg = "Floating-point underflow"        ; break;
      case FPE_FLTRES: msg = "Floating-point inexact result"   ; break;
      case FPE_FLTINV: msg = "Floating-point invalid operation"; break;
      case FPE_FLTSUB: msg = "Subscript out of range"          ; break;
      default: msg = "Unknown FPE";
    }

    char *msgend=buf;
    msgend = stpncpy (msgend,"Received SIGFPE. Reason: ", BUF_SZ - (msgend-buf));
    msgend = stpncpy (msgend, msg,                        BUF_SZ - (msgend-buf));
    msgend = stpncpy (msgend, ".\n",                      BUF_SZ - (msgend-buf));

    write (STDERR_FILENO, buf, msgend - buf);
  }

  exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main() {
  struct sigaction sa_fpe = {
    .sa_sigaction = sigfpe_hdl,
    .sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO,
  };
  sigaction (SIGFPE, &sa_fpe, 0);
  
  feenableexcept (FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
  
  int i,j;
  
//  i=10; j=0; i=i/j;  // integer divide by zero

   float x, y;

//   x = 10.0;  y= 0.0;   x = x/y;  // divide by zero
//   x = 1e+25; y= 1e+25; x = x*y;  // overflow          
//   x = 1e-25; y= 1e-25; x = x*y;  // underflow
//   x = 0.2;   y= 0.1;   x = x+y;  // inexact result
//   x = 0.0;   y= 0.0;   x = x/y;  // invalid operation
}
```

---

<sup>¹ Аналогичного результата можно добиться с помощью стандартных `fegetenv()`+`fesetexceptflag()`+`fsetenv()`.</sup>

Comment: Неужели по [siglongjmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/siglongjmp) восстановиться не получается?

Comment: @avp, получится почти наверняка, но это, во-первых, не то «чего хочется» — надо предварительно устанавливать точку возврата и потеряются все вычисления между оной и местом в котором произошла ошибка... во-вторых, когда писал ответ, где-то краем глаза увидел заявление, о том, что с точки зрения POSIX `longjmp` из обработчика сигнала — это UB (хотя мог просто очитаться или прочитать не до конца)...

Comment: * последние, скорей всего, — несуразность, конечно...

Comment: Конечно, longjmp не самый лучший вариант. Его использование системозависимо и  по сути толкает нас на мороку с созданием контрольных точек. Впрочем, для  серьезных (долго считающих что-либо) программ это может быть и плюсом.